# Wordpress PHP Plugin file_put_contents / Filesystem

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to create a file in my Wordpress plugin when saving the Metabox (admin area) and fill it with content. Unfortunately, php file_put_content does not allow me to create a file. Nevertheless absolute path from plugin_dir_path(**DIR**). The file should be completely overwritten each time it is saved.

```
define (PLUGINPATH,plugin_dir_path(__DIR__));
add_action('save_post','arti_carousel_save'); //Save Code
function arti_carousel_save( $post_id )
{
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$file = 'test.txt';
file_put_contents(PLUGINPATH.$file, $date);
}
```

Comment: I have found a solution:

[link]https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130215/call-to-a-member-function-put-contents-on-a-non-object/348602#348602[link]